# How to generate Spherical Perlin Noise Texture

Tags: shader, hlsl, noise

I have a very basic problem, for an explosion shader I need some spherical perlin noise inside a 2D texture like this one.
http://bugman123.com/Fractals/Perlin-sphere.jpg
http://stevencraeynest.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/easy-volumetric-explosion-in-unity3d/

Now I know that when I take the vertex position and use this as input inside a Noise3D function I get a sphere with seamless noise on it, but I have no idea how to bake this into a texture. I need a tool which can pre-render me some of these, anyone knows a solution to my problem?